# RVM installation of Ruby fails on "File name too long"

Tags: ruby, rvm

Trying to install Ruby (1.9.3) on OS X 10.9, fails with the following error:

```
/Users/me.me/.rvm/tmp/rvm_src_1235/win32 to /Users/me.me/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p327: File name too long
```

How can I fix this and install ruby?

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on, but see [this](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/1791) and [this](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2111)

Comment: what other information could help?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was causing the issue, but turns out 'sudo'ing worked. ($ **sudo** rvm install ruby 1.9.3).